# Sql queries with Aggregates

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have have problems with 2 sql queries.

Query 1:
I need to extract the maximum payment and the mode of payment from a table called payments.

My query:

```
SELECT MAX(totalPayment) AS MAXIMUM_PAYMENT, FROM Payments
```

Problem : I want to get the mode of payment as well but I can only get the maximum payment.

Query 2:
I need to extract the nurses who are not looking after any admitted patients.

My query:

```
 SELECT firstName , lastName FROM Nurse_Information
```

Problem: I have not completed the above query since I don't know what to give for the where clause. I have a column called `admittedPatient_No`, in the `Nurse_Information` table. 
If a nurse is not looking after an admitted patient, the column `admittedPatient_No` stays `null`.

How do I solve the query problems?

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Not enough info,where is mode of payment,why cant you get it?

Comment: its in the same table , but i don't know how to combine it to the query.

Comment: You might want to do a basic sql course/tutorial, before you get yourself in a right mess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like

```
SELECT Payment_method, MAX(totalPayment) AS MAXIMUM_PAYMENT FROM Payments
Group By Payment_method
```

will do the first the second isn't an aggregate unless you missed something in your question

```
Select firstName,lastName From NurseInformation
Where admmitedPatient_no is null
```